# Modify the slider to be automatic zoom

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-canvas

How can I make this slider automatically zoom-in and zoom-out for each image without clicking the image in an interval time?

http://www.dhteumeuleu.com/in-second-lives

Please give some idea of how to start this.

```
 setTimeout(         
        function() { 
         if (camera.over) {
                if (camera.over === camera.target.elem) {
                    camera.target.elem = camera.over;
                    camera.target.x = 50;
                    camera.target.z = 1500;
                    camera.target.x = 0;
                    camera.target.z = 0;
                    camera.target.elem = false;
                    // ---- adapt tesselation level to distance ----
                    for (var i = 0, d; d = diapo[i++];) {
                        var dx = camera.target.x - d.pc.x;
                        var dz = camera.target.z - d.pc.z;
                        var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dz * dz);
                        var lev = (dist > 1500) ? quality[0] : quality[1];
                        d.img.setLevel(lev);
                    }

                    camera.target.x = 100;
                    camera.target.z = 200;
                    camera.target.elem = false;

                    return ;
                    } else {
                    // ---- goto diapo ----
                    camera.target.elem = camera.over;
                    camera.target.x = camera.over.tx;
                    camera.target.z = camera.over.tz;
                    // ---- adapt tesselation level to distance ----
                    for (var i = 0, d; d = diapo[i++];) {
                        var dx = camera.target.x - d.pc.x;
                        var dz = camera.target.z - d.pc.z;
                        var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dz * dz);
                        var lev = (dist > 1500) ? quality[0] : quality[1];
                        d.img.setLevel(lev);
                    }
                }
             }
        }
,10000);
```

Thanks

Comment: oh my god, this is amazingly addicting...

Comment: hi . is it not possible ?

Comment: Actually, I did not get your question at all. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to "automatically" zoom-in zoom-out images without clicking (like a slideshow) ?

Comment: Yes  you are correct , i want to automatically zoom in and zoom out the images without clicking the image like a Slide Show.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a suggestion. I'm not giving you the whole code, but this idea should suffice:

Look at the code for the `tap()` function in the source. That is the function which handles the camera "zooming in, out, panning, and dollying". So now, the `tap()` function is called only when you click your mouse button on an image. Instead of waiting for a pointer `tap`, you can use setTimeout in the `run()` function to do an automatic zooming.

The key are the `pointer` and the `run` functions. Play around with them, and you'll stumble upon the solution.

Comment: Hi , but how can i get the camera position . while calling settimeout function

Comment: You know the position of the images na? So then just iterate through the image array, and set the camera to the co-ordinates of each image one after the other.

Comment: Hi , When i have using the setTimeout in the run function it works  continuosly , and also it is working during an event (when i am mouse over on it  ).

Comment: Oh, but you've not specified exactly what you need, so its hard to give a coherent answer.

Comment: @Raj: I think what you are looking for is a "Carousel". Search on google, you'll get a lot of results and resources.